# why rake tasks are not executing using and operator?

Tags: ruby, rake-task, rakefile

I have a rake task :

```
task :kill_process do
  system %q(ps -ef | awk '{if($8~"java" || $8~"glassfish" || $8~"ruby" || $8~"god" || $8~"couch"){printf("Killing : %s \n",$2);{system("kill -9 "$2)};}}')
end
```

This is basically killing processes. And this task is a part of another rake task :

```
desc "stop the entire system"
task :stop => [...., :kill_process]
```

There's another task:

```
desc "start the entire system"
task :start => [....]
```

When I am doing `rake stop && rake start`
stop task is executed successfully. but rake start is not executing.

If i execute both tasks separately, then it works fine. but not in `rake stop && rake start`

What will be better to use here exec function or system or any other, please suggest me.

My only requirement is to kill these mentioned processes at the end of `rake stop`. But also it should not effect other things like `rake stop && rake start` should work fine.

Comment: what does `syatem ` do?

Comment: I used it here, just to execute the linux command. Sorry that was a spell mistake. I have edited the code

Comment: I don't think `rake stop` returns successfully. Can you check the exit code of your rake command with `echo $?` on the command line.

Comment: Consider having a `restart` task which invokes `stop` and `start` for you.

Comment: @ChristianBruckmayer, echo $? is giving 137 as output

Comment: If the exit code is `137` your first command does evaluate to false and does not execute the second one because of `&&`. See my answer for options.

Comment: BTW, killing every process matching `glassfish`, `ruby`, `god`, or `couch` via `kill -9` might not be the best approach. It could match unrelated processes and `-9` could result in data loss.

Comment: @Stefan Can you suggest me the best way to do it

Comment: Figure out how to gracefully stop each process / service and take the appropriate actions. Maybe you have to store the pids somewhere. Maybe there is a dedicated command. It really depends.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the exit code is `137` which evaluates to false and therefore the other part of the `&&` does not get executed. The reason for this is probably `kill -9`.

There are a few options now.

1. Return 0 from your rake task, something like `exit(0)`
2. Don't use `kill -9`
3. Create `restart` command which does execute `stop` and `start` but without logically depending on each other (`&&`).

Comment: if i use ```exec``` method, then rake stop && rake start is working fine. As per my knowledge method exec doesn't return anything. would there be any effect with this?

Answer (score 1):

Exit code 137 indicates that a process has received a `SIGKILL` signal and was thus killed from the outside.

This happens since a Rake task is also executed by Ruby. As such, your stop task is sending a `SIGKILL` to its own process too (along with all other Ruby processes on the system). Now, since you have specified that you only want to execute the `rake start` process if the previous process was successful (i.e. had a exit code of `0`), your shell doesn't start the rake task.

To quickly fix this, you can instead run `rake stop; rake start`, i.e run the two processes regardless of their individual exit codes (by default).

However, a better idea would probably to make your stop task more explicit and only kill the specific processes you need rather than everything in sight which looks slightly like a related process. This will likely result in a more stable system overall too when you don't kill potentially unrelated processes all the time.

Comment: if i use exec method, then rake stop && rake start is working fine. As per my knowledge method exec doesn't return anything. would there be any effect with this?

Comment: @NitinSinghal `exec` replaces the current process, so you would step out of rake.

Comment: @Stefan, can there be problem with this, as this exec will be my last task in rake stop

Comment: @NitinSinghal imagine a `restart` task which invokes `rake stop` and `rake start`. If the former uses `exec`, the latter will never be executed.

Comment: @Stefan Did you mean to say, if former uses ```exec``` then after it's execution completes. This won't allow rest tasks to execute?

Comment: @NitinSinghal the moment you call `exec`, you are leaving Ruby. (think of calling `exit!` from withing your task) You don't want to do that, as it will likely break rake.

Comment: @Stefan, if i create a task say ```restart``` and for this task, i write ```[:stop, :start]```. Then will it work. or the ```false``` returned value of rake stop will affect this also?