# Format string in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, format, string-formatting

I have a string and a variable, i want to use this varaible inside this string, so it will take that value before converting it to string:

```
current_process_id = 222
ruby_command = %q(ps -x | awk '{if($5~"ruby" && $1!= %d ){printf("Killing ruby process: %s \n",$1);}};')
puts ruby_command
```

I tried :

```
current_process_id = 222
ruby_command = %q(ps -x | awk '{if($5~"ruby" && $1!= %d ){printf("Killing ruby process: %s \n",$1);}};') % [current_process_id]
puts ruby_command
```

But this is giving error :

```
main.rb:2:in `%': too few arguments (ArgumentError)
```

I tried :

```
awk_check = %q(ps -x | awk '{if) + "(" + %q($5~"ruby" && $1!=)
print_and_kill = %q({printf("Killing ruby process: %s \n",$1);{system("kill -9 "$1)};}};')
ruby_process_command = awk_check  + current_process_id.to_s + ")" + print_and_kill
puts ruby_process_command
```

This works fine for me. But the way i did is not clean.

I'm looking for more cleaner way to do it.

Comment: You seem to be asking the [same](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62536123/477037) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62532464/477037) [again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62514804/477037) [and](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62509528/477037) [again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62464476/477037) :-) I know these are different aspects, but maybe you should take the time to ask about / explain the problem as a whole?

Comment: @NitinShinghal: You have two format specifies (`%d` and `%s`) in the string to the left of your `%`-operator and a one-element array as the right operand. Your problem can be more simple described as `%q(%d %s) % [222]`, which will also show the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **ruby_command** variable, you have declared two positional arguments( **%d** and **%s**), whereas you only pass one value **[current_process_id]**. You need to pass the second value as well for **%s**.

Change your code to:

```
current_process_id = 222
ruby_command = %q(ps -x | awk '{if($5~"ruby" && $1!= %d ){printf("Killing ruby process: %s \n",$1);}};') % [current_process_id,current_process_id.to_s] 
puts ruby_command
```

Output:

```
ruby_command                                                                                                                                                                        
=> "ps -x | awk '{if($5~\"ruby\" && $1!= 222 ){printf(\"Killing ruby process: 222 \\n\",$1);}};'"
```

If you don't want to display the value, and you just want to display **"%s"**, you can just escape it with **%%**:

```
ruby_command = %Q(ps -x | awk '{if($5~"ruby" && $1!= %d ){printf("Killing ruby process: %%s \n",$1);}};') % [current_process_id]
```

Output:

```
ruby_command                                                                                                                                                                        
=> "ps -x | awk '{if($5~\"ruby\" && $1!= 222 ){printf(\"Killing ruby process: %s \n\",$1);}};'"
```